# Communication complexity of index problem with large domains

Tags: randomized-algorithms, communication-complexity

In the standard definition of the Index problem in one-way 2-party communication complexity, there are two players, Alice and Bob. Alice gets a binary input vector $x$ of length $n$ and Bob gets an index $i$. Alice can send a single message to Bob who must output $x_i$. It is known that this problem has a lower bound of $\Omega(n)$, even for randomized protocols.

**Question:**
Suppose that $x \in \{0,\dots,t-1\}^n$, for some integer $t\ge 2$. Is it known that the Index problem has an $\Omega(n\log t)$ lower bound in this case?